# To show that there exists a non-empty subset $A$ of $X$ such that $f(A) =A$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact metric space. Let $f: X \to X$ be continuous. To show that there exists a non-empty subset $A$ of $X$ such that $f(A) =A$.

Let us first consider $A_1 = f(X)$ and recursively then we consider $A_{n+1} = f(A_n)$. We see that $X$ being a compact metric space and $A_n$ being  a decreasing family with finite intersection property has non empty intersection. Thus the $A$ for which $f(A) = A$ will work is $\bigcap A_n$. I can feel it but unable to prove it!

Answer (score 3):

It is clear that $f(A) \subset A$. To show the converse direction, let $y \in A$. We want to show that $y \in f(A)$.

For any $n \in \Bbb{N}$, notice that $y \in A_{n+1}$ and thus we can pick $x_n \in A_n$ satisfying $f(x_n) = y$. Using the sequential compactness, extract a subsequence $(x_{n_j})$ that converges to some $x$. Then $x \in A_{n_j} \subset A_j$ for every $j$ and thus $x \in A$ with $f(x) = y$.